Can't find the 'No Access' permission in Cortex M55 MPU
I'm trying to configure the MPU region, but I can't find the 'No Access' permission.
There are only Read/Write permission.
How can I configure a memory region to 'No Access' in Cortex M55?
I read a document Cortex M55 Generic User Guide.

If you want an area of memory to be completely inaccessible, then you simply wouldn't include it in any MPU region.  Also, you'd need to turn off the PRIVDEFENA bit in the MPU_CTRL register, so that there is no default permission to access memory.

This issue is fixed by applying the patch disabling PRIVDEFENA! Thank you!!!
